# Angular-7 - How to create hybrid network and bubble chart

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, angular7, ng2-charts

I have requirement to design a chart with hybrid of network and bubble chart in `Angular-7`. The result looks something like in the image below [image] It also should show the flow of data like there in the site [Union Budget 2020](https://union2020.openbudgetsindia.org/en/). I am using `chart.js` and `ng2-charts` in angular-7. Is there a way around to design such graph in `chart.js` or need to use some other library? I have gone through these libraries as of now:

1. [Vis Network](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/)
2. [D3](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery)
3. [GoJS](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html)

but did not found the perfect one.

Comment: I checked the html of the site Union Budget 2020, they use d3.js to implement this. And the soure code is also directly available in the html <script> tag. Maybe you can lean something from there :)

Comment: this might help you https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/network-graph/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=7754cd5930c43baf4cae4b6f257227b4020cd51f-1587122225-0-AX3xdXMkeuXmgLSRFmg8qs96l_QT2rdQ3tTAHMpL_vLd_Z-n7pf-l__UdJLtAglFXb2dr5zV3GivdykzS8l6rGEnfs9mrS20ot0NtK1XxE-wcdIfxCg0XxdazRQEbzRkIo7PsIZducK1qYlb_AmTA6sJwjKemUzWZXtsUbR7bqwQFff4zwGITBv8gmIrH2zIyRA8wm8Qx1yAUbQFrpkIZo3kCEdEGIW6zEo6pjL32Gv9pIBNEQC6eHy9ysUL9Cj_VnrhBAyiswyRMOh-VNJ8S8RlHWxzshFF6HHRtInpdcBkRv9Rm22gA6bcKOT_7cj6uxAvmY6uliBM3LTnROZBcwD23_8bOouKHBuXHnfa4FJtURGIsAE2CrUw07PJ_dFDbA

Comment: @PhineasJ Yeah it is

Answer (score 1):

Vis Network should work. Check out this example

https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/scalingNodesEdges.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34882765)